# I am beginner and I have trying to learn to learn python so I have problem with this python code(if else statements)

Tags: python, if-statement

At the line 6 I nested if else statement in the print statement and can you help with finding another solution for this

```
age = int(input('How old are you:' ));

 if age > 18:
    print('You are welcome to use our services');
else:
    print('sorry,we can\'t give you our services we can give this services after ' + str(18 
- age ) + str(
    if str(18 - age) = 1:
        print('year')
    else:
        print('years')
))
```

Comment: why use `str(18 - age)`? The result is a number, not text. And you compare it to a number. Also, the comparison should be `==`, not an assigment.

Comment: For the else case you can use ternary as print('sorry,we can\'t give you our services we can give this services after ' + str(18 - age ) + ' year' if 18-age == 1 else ' years')

Comment: `y = 18 - age; print('... after', y, 'year' if y == 1 else 'years')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
age = int(input('How old are you:' ))
if age > 18:
    print('You are welcome to use our services')
else:
  diff = 18-age
  if diff == 1:
    aux = 'year'
  else:
    aux = 'years'
  print('sorry,we can\'t give you our services we can give this services after',diff,aux)
```